# Using Past Perfect in English conversation

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect

I called call center executive yesterday but I did not received proper reply from him. Hence again today I called to call center again and start my conversation as below.

Me: Hi, My Name is XYZ and my problem is ABC

Executive: Sorry, you dialed wrong extension please dial 123

Me: I had called on that extension but I was connected to this extension. I had also called yesterday to that extension but did not received proper reply from your executive, Please transfer me to desire extension if possible.

Was my part of conversation was correct or do I need to have better conversation in any other way?
Specially using past perfect tense. Actually I wanted to focus on past completed action.

Comment: The simple past is sufficient in both sentences: the core meaning of the simple past is a 'past completed action'.

Comment: I think your conversation sounds fine. However, if you want to be even more clear (and perhaps to express even more of your displeasure), you could say, "I *did* try that extension *and* had tried it yesterday as well, but..." to emphasize that you had done this action both the day before as well as the day of the call.

Answer (score 2):

If you are actually on the phone and talking about the number you just dialled to achieve that call, then you would not say ' I had called on that extension but I was connected to this extension', you would instead say 'I did call on that extension ...' or 'I called on that extension ...'. This would indicate that the action of calling the number was recent and linked to the current call.

By saying 'I had called on that extension' makes it sound like a previous call that you made and not related to the current call.

The rest of the conversation is fine in regards to past tense.

Comment: Why did you delete [your other answer](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/122325/does-the-watch-which-i-bought-from-japan-is-a-birthday-present-for-my-sister). It was correct (but the last paragraph needed more explanation/illustration).